# wordpress podscms

Tags: wordpress, podscms

In wordpress podscms when i make a relationship pick. it entry in the
database occur in the other table not in the same table of my content
type as the other fields entry happen.

Comment: So what is the question exactly ?

Comment: relationship (pick) entry in the same table database
new to pods i m facing the problem in realationship(pick) when using for a custom post type when i used it as a feild. its entry occur in the other table not on the same table. I want its relationship value to save in that same table like others feild entry happen.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I've answered your question already on our own Q&A site:

http://podscms.org/qna/questions/2304/relationship-pick-entry-in-the-same-table-database